# custom AlertDialog with layout

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Im trying to get the content of the editText, but idont know how to do it. Please help me in  this.(Im using the method showDialog)

```
protected  Dialog onCreateDialog(int id, Bundle args)
{
        AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        builder2.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_search_teacher,null));
        final EditText price,city;
        price=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.price_search);
        city=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.city_search);
        builder2.setPositiveButton("Serach", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                serach(city.getText().toString(),price.getText().toString());

            }
        });
        builder2.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert2 = builder2.create();
        return(alert2);}
```

Comment: What's the problem you are having? Also, is the `EditText` inside the layout set in `setContentView()` or in `dialog_search_teacher.xml`?

Comment: Unrelated bro-tip: Use `LayoutInflater.from(builder2.getContext())`. I.e. use the context with dialog theme to inflate contents of a dialog. This will most notably fix incorrect font color in black dialogs over white activities and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get the text from the EditText you have to do this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_search_teacher, null);
city=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.city_search);
```

and then, on the onclick() method you have to retrieve the text:

```
city.getText().toString();
```

but if you want to pass the string to the parent class you have to do an interface like this:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score -2):

You have to find editText id like this

price=(EditText)builder2.findViewById(R.id.price_search);

Answer (score -2):

You should declaration your editText under the dialog method like,

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_search_teacher, null);
city=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.city_search);
```

After that, while doing onClick listener for postive button, you can get the content of editText using

```
city.getText().toString();
```

Hope this will help you.